# Can't get my Phaser game to work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, phaser-framework

I have a Phaser 2/CE game that I have hosted on my website. It works perfectly in Chrome and Safari on a desktop. I want it mobile friendly, so I added the mobile code in my index and boot.js files, but it doesn’t work on my iPhone when I try to play it on my website through my Iphone. When I view it through my phone, it crashes right after the boot.js file. Works perfectly on desktop, but crashes on my iPhone. Can someone help me get this to work on mobile? Below is my code for my index file and my boot.js file.

Index file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
                               maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
     
<title>Keytar Kitty!</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser-ce/2.10.0/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/phaser-state-transition-plugin.min.js"></script>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P');
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Princess+Sofia');
</style>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/splash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/splash2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/gameOver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main10.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main11.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main12.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main13.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main14.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main15.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main16.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main17.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main18.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main19.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main20.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/main21.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/menu.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/load.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="superpop_assets/config.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
.yes{

    background-color: black;
}

.hiddenText{

    font-family: 'Press Start', cursive;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.hiddenText2{

    font-family: 'Princess Sofia', cursive;
    visibility: hidden;
}
    
    *{
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }
    
</style>

<body class="yes">
<br>
<br>
<br>

<center>
<div id="gameDiv"> </div>

<p class="hiddenText">.</p>
<p class="hiddenText2">.</p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

boot.js file:

```js
var bootState = {
preload: function () {
// Load the image
game.load.image('progressBar', 'superpop_assets/progressBar.png');
game.load.image('madmodemlogo', 'superpop_assets/madmodemlogo.png');
game.load.image('rrrlogo', 'superpop_assets/rrrlogo.png');
game.load.audio('menusong', 'superpop_assets/menusong.mp3');
},
    
    
create: function() {
    
// Set some game settings game.stage.backgroundColor = '#3498db'; game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
              // Start the load state
              game.stateTransition = this.game.plugins.add(Phaser.Plugin.StateTransition);

    //game.plugins.screenShake = this.game.plugins.add(Phaser.Plugin.ScreenShake);
    
    
 // If the device is not a desktop, so it's a mobile device
if (!game.device.desktop) {
    
    
// Set the type of scaling to 'show all' 
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    
    
          // Add a blue color to the page, to hide the white borders we might have
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#3498db';
    
    
          // Set the min and max width/height of the game
          game.scale.minWidth = 250;
          game.scale.minHeight = 170;
          game.scale.maxWidth = 1000;
          game.scale.maxHeight = 680;
    
    
          // Center the game on the screen
game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true; 
game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
    
          // Apply the scale changes
game.scale.setScreenSize(true); 


}   

              game.state.start('load');

game.stateTransition.configure({
  duration: Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2,
  ease: Phaser.Easing.Exponential.InOut,
  properties: {
    alpha: 0,
    scale: {
      x: 1.6,
      y: 1.6
    }
  }
});
          }
};
```

menu.js

```
var menuState = {


    create: function() {


    

    //menu music
    //this.menumusic = game.add.audio('menusong');
   // this.menumusic.volume = 0.2;
    //this.menumusic.play();

    //press start sound
    this.pressstart = game.add.audio('pressstart');
    this.pressstart.volume = 0.2;
      
    // Add a background image 
    this.test = game.add.sprite(390, 295, 'background');
    this.test.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
    this.test.scale.setTo(2, 2);
    

    // Display the name of the game above the actual game
    var nameLabel = game.add.image(30, -600, 'logo');
    nameLabel.anchor.setTo(0.52, 0.5);




    //var nameLabel = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, -50, 'Super Pop Icon Destroy', { font: '30px Press Start 2P', fill: '#ffffff' });
    //nameLabel.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);


    //tweening the nameLabel
    //putting it at an ending point
    this.game.add.tween(nameLabel).to({y: 300, x:425}, 1200).easing(Phaser.Easing.Bounce.Out).start();


    //Tweening the statt label
    //this.game.add.tween(startLabel).to({y:100, x:100}, 1000).easing(Phaser.Easing.Bounce.Out).start();



    // Show the score at the center of the screen
    /*var scoreLabel = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'score: ' + game.global.score,
    { font: '25px Press Start 2P', fill: '#ffffff' });
    scoreLabel.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5); */

    // Explain how to start the game
    var startLabel = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, game.world.height-35, 'Press Up To Start',
    { font: '20px Press Start 2P', fill: '#ffffff' });

    startLabel.alpha = 0;
     this.game.add.tween(startLabel).to( { alpha: 1 }, 2000, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true, 0, 1000, true);

    startLabel.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);

    // Create a new Phaser keyboard variable: the up arrow key
    var upKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.UP);


    // When the 'upKey' is pressed, it will call the 'start' function once
    upKey.onDown.addOnce(this.start, this); 

    
    },







update: function(){

    //turn the background around continuously
    this.test.angle +=0.8;
    },


    

    // Start the actual game 
start: function() {
    //game.state.start('main');
    game.stateTransition.to('main');
    this.pressstart.play();
    this.menumusic.stop();
    }, 





};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is an error, that the function `setScreenSize` throws.

**Something like:**

> *... game.scale.setScreenSize is not a function...*

An as mentioned in [the documentation](https://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.ScaleManager.html#setScreenSize) or [in this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/105141/160123), this function doesn't exist anymore, hence the error.

> **This method is deprecated and should not be used. It may be removed in the future....**
> ... *Do not call this directly. To "refresh" the layout use [refresh](https://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.ScaleManager.html#refresh). To precisely control the scaling/size, apply appropriate rules to the bounding Parent container or use the USER_SCALE scale mode.*

**Possible solution:** use the function `refresh` or `updateLayout`, both display the app on a iPhone.

***btw.:** I seems, that there is a newer Phaser CE Version available 2.19.1*

**Update, how to debug your application:**
here is a nice article how to do this, in two different ways: https://www.browserstack.com/how-to-debug-on-iphone

**Or** you can debug ***old school***, add *print-statments*, that are written to the website and rap the parts which you think cause the problem with a `try/catch` - block and output the error on the page or in an `alert`.

**Here an example, how this could look like:**

```
try{ 
   ...
   document.body.innerHTML += `<div>* Before calling xyz </div>`
   ...
   document.body.innerHTML += `<div>* After calling xyz </div>`
   ...
} catch(e){
     document.body.innerHTML += `<div>!!! Error: ${e}</div>`
}
```

Comment: When I start the game, it goes through the boot.js file, then it loads two splash screens successfully, but right before it gets to the menu screen it stops and reloads the page and goes back to the boot.js file again. Ive added the menu code above.

Comment: @thesubhuman Sorry to hear, but only that you know stackoverflow is for helping users to [solve a specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), not to debug code in small increments. I updated in may answer, how you can debug your code.